# how to get partial template work with subclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a template generic with a struct and substruct,
but my code fail to infer the correct template.
this is the abstraction of my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A{

};
struct B{

};
struct AA:public A{

};
struct BB:public B{

};

template<class container>
class Base{

};
template<class container>
class Derived:Base<container>{
    Derived() = delete;
};
template<>
class Derived<A>:Base<A>{

};
template<>
class Derived<B>:Base<B>{

};
int main() {
    Derived<AA> a;
    return 0;
}
```

and got error

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'Derived<AA>'
```

i wish `struct A` and its subclass can be used with

```
template<>
class Derived<A>:Base<A>{

};
```

how can I do it, or what material should I refer to?
thx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the partial specialization like

```
// primary template
template<class container, class = void>
class Derived : Base<container> {
    Derived() = delete;
};

// partial specialization for A and its derived classes
template<class container>
class Derived<container, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, container>>> : Base<container> {
};
```

and also full specialization if necessary.

```
// full specialization for B
template<>
class Derived<B, void> : Base<B> {
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0ssxMJLgzsneiw2Z)

Comment: @jinzhenhui Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if you find it useful.